# Is it possible to connect 5 monitor in Dell 9010 desktop pc

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, displayport

My PC is Dell optiplex 9010. It has

- 2 Display port and 1 VGA on onboard (Total 3)
- 1 DVI port and 1 Display port on Radeon HD 7470 Graphic.

Currently i'm connected 3 display (2 on Graphic card, 1 vga on board). 2 Display port free on board.

Is there possible to connect another 2 monitor using 2 display port. 
Currently i don't have additional display. If it is possible, i will buy 2 monitor, monitor stand holder and DVI to DP converters. But before i want to know it is possible.

Note: i'm trying to unplug 1 monitor (with DP) from graphic card and plug to onboard Dispay port and display normal work. But i don't know any monitor limitation or other things.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation of DisplayPort on that board, but you can chain upto 5 monitors from one display port connector if it meets standard version 1.2, and you drop your resolution down.

https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

Comment: But in my situation 2 free Display Port available. I want use these 2 slots.

Comment: @ebattulga - You can't use both the iGPU and the dGPU for your displays with the hardware you have.